# Split data into multiple workbooks keeping the same layout and Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, split, format

I have the following code, it works well, but it won’t keep the page settings, formats or formulas. How do I fix the code so the information is split into a workbook and still holds all the formatting from parent file?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Split_Data_in_workbooks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim data_sh As Worksheet
Set data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comm")

Dim setting_Sh As Worksheet
Set setting_Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")

Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet

''''' Get unique Sales Groups

data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False

' Copy
data_sh.Range("B:B").Copy
' Paste Special
setting_Sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
setting_Sh.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
setting_Sh.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Application.CountA(setting_Sh.Range("A:A"))

data_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value


Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)

data_sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nsh.Range("A1")
nsh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15

nwb.SaveAs setting_Sh.Range("H6").Value & "/" & setting_Sh.Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx"
nwb.Close False
data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
Next i

setting_Sh.Range("A:A").Clear

MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is unclear but perhaps make a copy of the worksheet to a new workbook then remove what you don't want in the new copied worksheet?

Comment: See here: [XlPasteType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype).. `xlPasteFormats` and `xlPasteColumnWidths` could be of use to you

Comment: @Raymond Wu Thank you, but that doesn't help. This code takes a massive datasheet, splits it into separate workbooks without me having to do all the manual copy and paste into separate workbooks. What I want is for the code to maintain page settings when it splits into the numerous workbooks.

Comment: @Dean Thank you! I'll check those out!